# How to resolve unfindable stored procedure error

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a database that I want to configure database mail for, to be activated by a trigger. I found and followed some online tutorials and got this.

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO 
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure'Database Mail XPs',1;
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO

EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profile_sp
    @profile_name='Notifications',
    @description='Profile for sending outgoing notifications using Gmail.';
GO

EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_principalprofile_sp  
    @profile_name = 'Notifications',  
    @principal_name = 'public',  
    @is_default = 1 ;
GO

EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_account_sp  
    @account_name = 'Gmail',  
    @description = 'Mail account for sending outgoing notifications.',  
    @email_address = 'my_email',  
    @display_name = 'Automated Mailer',  
    @mailserver_name = 'smtp.gmail.com',
    @port = 465,
    @enable_ssl = 1,
    @username = 'my_email',
    @password = 'My_password' ;  
GO


EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profileaccount_sp  
    @profile_name = 'Notifications',  
    @account_name = 'Gmail',  
    @sequence_number =1 ;  
GO

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
     @profile_name = 'Notifications',
     @recipients = 'my_email',
     @body = 'The database mail configuration was completed successfully.',
     @subject = 'Automated Success Message ';
GO
```

It worked fine until I tried  to send a test email, it would only give me this:

```
Mail (Id: 9) queued.
```

I then visited the SQLserver documentation to trouble shoot the issue, and I run this:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced', 1;  
RECONFIGURE; 
EXEC sp_configure; 
GO
sysmail_help_queue_sp @queue_type = 'Mail' ;
```

But I get this weird error:

> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 74
> Could not find stored procedure 'sysmail_help_queue_sp'

How can I rectify this issue?

Comment: https://www.exacthelp.com/2012/11/could-not-find-stored-procedure.html

Comment: Have you set your database context to MSDB?

Comment: `It worked fine until I tried to send a test email, it would only give me this:

Mail (Id: 9) queued.` Please do take a look at the documentation for `sp_send_dbmail`. It stated that `On success, returns the message "Mail queued."`

Comment: But nothing shows up in my inbox, also I have already set the database to MSDB.

Answer (score 0):

The database and owner needed to be specified like this:

```
msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_queue_sp @queue_type = 'Mail';
```